# Is there something similar to the ClientDependency package for asp.net core (.net 6.0)?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In asp.net mvc 5 I used to use the ClientDependency nuget package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClientDependency) to mange client dependencies like css and js files. You would put e.g. @Html.RequiresJs("jquery-1.8.1.min.js", "Scripts", 1); into your view, and it would get rendered in the web page. Now this ClientDependency project seems to be abandoned and not updated to .net 6.0 (https://github.com/Shazwazza/ClientDependency/tree/master). So my question is: what is currently the best way to manage your js and css dependencies? After a bit of googling I get the impression that not many people have been using this kind of technique to manage dependencies.

Comment: I'd definitely discourage you from using syntax like "@Html.RequiresJs" going forward.  Personally, I like to put my "dependencies" (links to the current Bootstrap, jQuery, etc. etc.) files in a "master layout" under "Pages\Shared", and just keep the entire project under Git version control.

Comment: Why is that? Different pages can have different dependencies. And if I put them all in a single master layout, I don't know which js/css file was required by which page. This sounds like maintenance nightmare to me. For instance page X requires Y.css. If one year later I decide page X can be removed, all its dependencies are automatically removed as well. But if I would put all its dependencies in a master layout, then you can't easily figure out what referenced css/js etc can be cleaned up.

Comment: You realize, of course, that you can have multiple different layout pages.  You can also "include" a partial view from a separate .cshtml file.  The point is: it's easy to "manage your .js, .css and any other "markup resources" in ASP.Net .cshtml  ("markup") files.  And it's easy to track "changes" if you put your .cshtml under version control.  There's really little - or no - need for anything more complicated :)

Comment: Sure I can lookup my version control history, but that's rather clunky compared to how you could do it using ClientDependency. There's no actual downside to ClientDependency, just convenience. I can just require whatever js/css on a per page basis, like you would put using namespace at the top of your .cshtml file. Like namespaces you will have some shared ones that you put in a shared layout, but then there are specific ones that you use only in specific pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned today that the way to do this is using sections, it's pretty simple, here's an example, in your view you add for example a stylesheets section.

```
@section stylesheets {
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/test.css" />
}
```

And in the shared layout you put a RenderSectionAsync like this:

```
    @await RenderSectionAsync("stylesheets", required: false)
```

The only thing missing from the ClientDependency package is the potential dependency ordering (and perhaps handling duplicates), but this works well enough for now. Thanks everybody for their suggestions.

Comment: You also can use a partial view named _xxxScriptsPartial  to put your js, then use `@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_xxxScriptsPartial" />
}` in the shared layout .

Comment: That's neat. For now my web pages aren't very big, but that looks useful when there's a lot of javascript involved.